# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1039: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, nltk

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer= WordNetLemmatizer()
data1['lematized']=""
data1['lematized']=data1['punctuation_removal'].apply(lambda x 
:lemmatizer.lemmatize(x))
```

I am using this code to lemmatize the data in a natural language project but its returning error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1039: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried changing the default encoding to UTF-8 but it didn't worked.

and when I provide tokenized with tagging data as input it results in

```
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    lemmatizer= WordNetLemmatizer()
    data1['lematized']=""
    data1['lematized']=data1['word_tagging'].apply(lambda x :lemmatizer.lemmatize(x))

Error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please add the complete tracebacks for the errors.

Comment: Please provide the sample of the data file you used. Couldn't reproduce this issue.